# Laravel 4.0 cascade delete and polymorphic relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, cascade

I am using the Eloquent plymorphic relations and the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option of mysql, and am afraid of how my data will stay consistent over time. Let me explain:

If I have a model Room which contains furnitures of several types (morphMany of `Table`, `Chair`, `Couch`...), and that I decide to delete it, his related furnitures won't get deleted.

To solve this issure I handled the deletion of the related furnitures in the **delete event** of the `Room` model, but **this event won't necessarily get fired all the time**.

Let's say that I have an other model called `House`, containing several rooms (hasMany). If I decide to delete it, **its related models will deleted by mysql** with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option. I will then stay with data in my tables `tables`, `chairs`, `couchs` that are not relevant anymore, and not related to any row of the `rooms` table anymore.

So what is the best way to keep a database consistent with `ON DELETE CASCADE` and the Eloquent's polymorphic relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the raw database (cascading) approach, that bypasses Eloquent and it becomes impossible to do what you want.

Set up a deleted event for House which iterates through all its Rooms and deletes those, which again triggers the Room's deleted events.

Comment: So if I understand what you say, the ability to put cascade delete in the migrations should not actually be used ever, as all the deletion should be handled by Eloquent only. Am I right ?

Comment: Sometimes cascading works fine, but if you need more advanced logic on when to delete (as is your case), use model events.